# log4j2 how to select session instead of date

Tags: log4j, log4j2

On log4j2 I can easily log to file based on date as per the following line.

```
<File name="file" fileName="logs/te_${date:yyyy}-${date:MM}-${date:dd}_output.log" append="true">
```

On some industries there is the **concept of session that spans across midnight**.
Say cinema, on some countries movies start after midnight.
So I would like the logs to be captured as sessions that would end/start at 4AM.

Any time of day where you would start program it would check:

```
// pseudo code
if time < 04:00 then
    session = today.minusDays(1)
else 
    session = today
```

So, to make it clear, logfile name when program starts would be the following:

```
# starting datetime |  logfile name
2020-05-20 22:00 -> "2020-05-20_output.log"
2020-05-21 01:00 -> "2020-05-20_output.log"
2020-05-21 03:00 -> "2020-05-20_output.log"
2020-05-21 05:00 -> "2020-05-21_output.log"
```

Anyway I can do this on log4j2.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

If isn't really clear what you want to have happen at 4AM. It sounds like you want to start writing to a different file. If so, you want to use the RollingFileAppender with the CronTriggeringPolicy.

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile" filePattern="logs/te_%d{yyyy:MM:dd}_output.log">
  <PatternLayout>
    <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
  <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 4 * * ?"/>
</RollingFile>
```

Comment: thks for answer but it's not a rolling I'm after. It's to have the program start in one day but give the logfile a different day. I updated the question with a better example. Up until 4am I still want the program to log to the previous day's log. Even if I start the program at 1am.

You example would work if it worked continuously which is not the case. Sorry, should have given more detail in the question.